# Protecting static content served by Apache

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat

I have a Tomcat server running some Jersey RESTful services and I'm using Apache to host the static content.  The static content for the most part is empty, and the content is filled out via RESTful calls, but aside from the login page, I don't want anyone to be able to browse to the other static pages directly.  We have an authentication servlet that filters any requests to the REST services, but I was wondering what the best approach would be to handle the static content.  I'd rather not be serving static content via Tomcat if at all possible.

Edit: I should mention that only the login page should be directly accessible with no need to be filtered, etc.

Comment: So you want the static file request to go through your servlet and then have the servlet fulfill the request from Apache?  Seems like you'll be losing the benefit of serving the static files through Apache if the request goes through Tomcat anyway

Comment: No, I'd rather serve all static content via Apache and only the REST calls going through Tomcat.  At the same time, I want to try to limit access to a certain number of static files if the user hasn't authenticated, which is being done via some REST calls that set a session variable.

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind would be setting a Cookie when the user authenticates that you could then check for in Apache using `mod_rewrite`.  Not sure if that works for you though...

Comment: Actually that may work...  We are setting a cookie using the HTTP session, so I "should" be able to check for that.  Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind would be setting a `Cookie` when the user authenticates that you could then check for in Apache using `mod_rewrite`.

Not sure if that works for you though...

Let me know if you'd like an example `RewriteRule`.

EDIT - example rule:

Assuming static content resides in a `/static/` directory, the following **should** result in a `401 Forbidden` if the user hasn't logged in (resulting in the cookie having a value of `authenticated=true`)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/static\/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !authenticated=true
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

I have used this method for directing mobile traffic, but not for restricting secure content, so I would recommend some thorough testing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I remember hearing that an mp3 sharing website in the late 90's made symbolic links with the session guid in them and then shared the URL as a static resource. Then they had a process that looked at the date created of the static resources and removed them after 30 minutes so they would fail if someone tried to share the URL. Works with any client and no cookies, not a bad approach.

Comment: This is perfect.  I'm using the HttpSession.setAttribute() now, but I can easily change that to a cookie.  An example RewriteRule would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but if I'm not too late, I've added an example that should help out.

Comment: @JohnS Hi I have the exact same requirement in my app. and I also had the same idea as clmarquart. But before i implement it can you please let me know if Solution really worked and any possible issues i should be aware of? I will also update my experience afterwards

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan I ended up going with a different solution actually, so I can't comment on this.  It was decided that the static assets were not that valuable, so there wasn't a need to implement clmarquart's solution.